# How to save a plot to disc with tmap in R

Tags: r, sp, sf, ggmap

I have made a plot with these lines

```
mainland 
print(Bornhold, vp = viewport(x = 0.7, y = 0.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.2))
```

[image]
One is mainland and the other an island. How can I save it to one one png file. I have found this [link](https://rdrr.io/cran/tmap/man/tmap_save.html) with the documentation but it only takes one object but the plot has two objects?

Comment: How did you include the image in the question?

Comment: @Spacedman: A screenshot.

Comment: And what's wrong with that as a solution to your problem?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add more of the code, including libraries, that you used to produce the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this code to save the file as png

```
png("logo.png")
mainland 
print(Bornhold, vp = viewport(x = 0.91, y = 0.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.2))
dev.off()
list.files(pattern = "png")
```

I works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plot that you'd like to save and didn't put (or don't like to put) the nested `png()` or `pdf()` followed by `dev.off()`, then you can use `dev.copy2pdf()` to save whatever is in the plot window as a PDF:

```
dev.copy2pdf(file = "myfile.pdf", width = 5, height = 3)
```

Unfortunately there isn't an option for PNG output that I'm aware of.